# Using -mkl Lapack routines in Fortran programs

Tags: fortran, lapack, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I am new to using the Math Kernel Library(mkl). I have a program that uses a system-of-linear-equations-solver( `gesv` routine) of LAPACK (which comes with MKL). I already have MKL (also Intel Parallel Studio XE) installed on my computer. I am having trouble compiling/linking the code. I compile the code using:

```
ifort -mkl matrixinv.f90
```

However, it gives the following error

```
/tmp/ifortjcXZTm.o: In function `MAIN__':
matrixinv.f90:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `gesv_'
```

The code is attached below

```
PROGRAM matrixinv
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL(8),DIMENSION(3,3)::A,C
INTEGER(4),DIMENSION(3)::IPVT
REAL(8)::RCOND
REAL(8),DIMENSION(3)::V,B
A(1,1)=3.0_8
A(1,2)=2.0_8
A(1,3)=-1.0_8
A(2,1)=2.0_8
A(2,2)=-2.0_8
A(2,3)=4.0_8
A(3,1)=-1.0_8
A(3,2)=0.5_8
A(3,3)=-1.0_8
B(1)=1.0_8
B(2)=-2.0_8
B(3)=0.0_8

call gesv(A,B)
PRINT*,B

END PROGRAM matrixinv
```

Comment: According to [Intel® MKL Link Line Advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor) you should use this : ` -mkl=sequential `

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to declare gesv as external. Add the following statement after the "implicit none":

```
external gesv
```

Comment: This is not required and does nothing to help the linker find the symbol.

Comment: I had the above line in my code before. Does not work.

Comment: No, the required USE mkl should appear in the examples for blas95 and replaces external.  It would be preferable if this were covered explicitly in link advisor.

Comment: @tim18 you are right, post your answer. You may want to add this link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/704022

Comment: @Dabu you may want to check https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/704022 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010018/how-can-i-link-mkl-to-compilation-to-get-missing-daxpy